# How to push item to array if checked in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, checkbox

I am mapping an array and checking with checkbox.
But I checking it in customCheckbox.
I want to push checked items to **involvedfriends:[]**

> How can I call checked state from Checkbox, and add checked item to array
>
> But I not quite sure how i will achieve it, hope someone can help me.

**My state**

```
state={involvedFriends:[]}
```

**AddFriendScreen**

```
{this.state.involvedFriends.map((name, key) => (
        <View>
          <CustomCheckbox name={name}/>
        </View>
      ))}
```

**CustomCheckbox**

```
this.state = {
  checked: false,
};

toggleChange = () => {
     this.setState({ checked: !this.state.checked })};

render() {
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Text style={styles.text}>{this.props.name}</Text>
    <CheckBox
      checked={this.state.checked}
      onPress={() => this.toggleChange()}
    />
  </View>
)}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can send toggle result to parent component using callback. there is two callback for add and remove item from array by check and uncheck your customCheckbox.

this is an example code:

**CustomCheckbox**

```
this.state = {
  checked: false,
};

toggleChange = () => {
     if (!this.state.checked){ // it is checking true now...
         this.prop.checkedTrue(this.props.name)
     } else {
         this.prop.checkedFalse(this.props.name)
     }
     this.setState({ checked: !this.state.checked })
};

render() {
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Text style={styles.text}>{this.props.name}</Text>
    <CheckBox
      checked={this.state.checked}
      onPress={() => this.toggleChange()}
    />
  </View>
)}
```

**AddFriendScreen**

```
puchToArray = (name) => {
    let tmp = this.state.involvedfriends
    tmp.push(name)
    this.setState({ involvedfriends: tmp })
}

removeFromArray = (name) => {
    let tmp = this.state.involvedfriends
    let index = tmp.indexOf(name);
    if (index>-1){
        tmp.splice(index, 1);
        this.setState({ involvedfriends: tmp })
    }
}


render:
        {this.state.involvedFriends.map((name, key) => (
            <View>
               <CustomCheckbox 
                   name={name}
                   checkedTrue = {(name) => {this.puchToArray(name)}}
                   checkedFalse = {(name) => {this.removeFromArray(name)}}
               />
            </View>
        ))}
```

I hope this can help you.

Comment: I've changed `puchToArray = (name) => {this.state.involvedfriends.push(name)}` to `this.setState({involvedFriends: [...this.state.involvedFriends, name], });` and it works

Comment: how can I rewrtite removeFromArray method, because it shows undefined, and I maybe need to use [..this.state.involveedFriends] **Any ideas?**

Comment: Error: "undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.state.involvedfriends.find')" in removeFromArray << checkedFalse << toggleChange << touchableHandlePress@[snack internals] ...

Comment: if your array is string, you can use indexof instead of find. find is use to check part of an object in an array. try this code...

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.

In your AddFriendScreen, pass this callback to each of your CustomCheckbox.

```
        <CustomCheckbox
            onChecked={(item) => {
                let array = this.state.involvedFriends;
                array.push(item);
                this.setState({
                    involvedFriends: array
                })
            }}
        />
```

Then in your CustomCheckbox, you may invoke the callback in `toggleChange`.

```
toggleChange = () => {
    if (!this.state.checked) {
        this.props.onChecked(this.props.name);
    }
    this.setState({
        checked: !this.state.checked
    });
}
```

This should add the name into the array whenever a checkbox is checked.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change like this

```
 constructor(props) {
        super();
        this.state = {
            involvedFriends: []
        }
        this.insertName= this.insertName.bind(this);
    }

    insertName(name, isChecked) {
        if (isChecked == true) {
            this.state.involvedFriends.push(name);
        } else {
         this.state.involvedFriends.splice(this.state.involvedFriends.indexOf(name), 1);
        }
    }

{this.state.involvedFriends.map((name, key) => (
        <View>
          <CustomCheckbox name={name} insertName={this.insertName}/>
        </View>
      ))
}
```

CustomCheckbox.js

```
this.state = {
  checked: false,
};

toggleChange = (name) => {
     this.setState({ checked: !this.state.checked })
     this.props.insertName(name, !this.state.isChecked)
};

render() {
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Text style={styles.text}>{this.props.name}</Text>
    <CheckBox
      checked={this.state.checked}
      onPress={() => this.toggleChange(this.props.name)}
    />
  </View>
)}
```